# Open a SWT modal on button click inside another SWT Framework in Java

Tags: java, eclipse, swt

I have wrote the following framework class. I would like to open a modal of somekind that will hold components (i.e. buttons, textboxes etc.) on button click. I have tried a JFrame and this works, however, I cannot get a consistent design to match the parent shell. For example, the buttons on JFrames look different than SWT shells.

When the button is clicked I get an error...

> Exception in thread "main" org.eclipse.swt.SWTException: Invalid thread access

Can this be done? If not, can anyone give me any other suggestions?

```
package framework;

import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.*;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.SelectionAdapter;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.SelectionEvent;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.InputEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

import framework.SWTResourceManager;

public class Frontend {

    /** Declare display, shell and data text objects */
    Display display = new Display();
    Shell shell = new Shell(display, SWT.CLOSE);

    private Button btnOpen;

    /** Initialise frame */
    public Frontend() {
        init();
        shell.pack();
        shell.open();
        shell.setSize(600, 600);
        while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
            if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
                display.sleep();
            }
        }
        display.dispose();
    }

    private void init() {
        // Set background of framework.
        shell.setBackground(SWTResourceManager.getColor(SWT.COLOR_WIDGET_LIGHT_SHADOW));

        btnOpen = new Button(shell, SWT.NONE);
        btnOpen.setForeground(SWTResourceManager.getColor(SWT.COLOR_BLACK));
        btnOpen.setText("Open");
        btnOpen.setBounds(20, 20, 50, 50);

        btnOpen.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {       
            @Override
            public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {      
                Display visual_display = new Display();
                Shell visual_shell = new Shell(visual_display, SWT.CLOSE | SWT.TITLE | SWT.MIN | SWT.MAX | SWT.ON_TOP);
                visual_shell.pack();

                // Set framework size.
                visual_shell.setSize(600,600);
                visual_shell.open();

                while (!visual_shell.isDisposed()) {
                    if (!visual_display.readAndDispatch()) {
                        visual_display.sleep();
                    }
                }
                visual_display.dispose();
            }
        });
    }

    // Run Frame.
    public static void main(String[] args) {
         new Frontend();
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't mix SWT with Swing/SWT it will cause endless problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your SWT code is creating a new `Display` when the button is pressed - you should not do this. An SWT app should only use a single `Display` object for the entire app.

So your selection listener should be something like:

```
    btnOpen.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {       
        @Override
        public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {      

            Shell visual_shell = new Shell(display, SWT.CLOSE | SWT.TITLE | SWT.MIN | SWT.MAX | SWT.ON_TOP);
            visual_shell.pack();

            // Set framework size.
            visual_shell.setSize(1010,600);
            visual_shell.open();

            while (!visual_shell.isDisposed()) {
                if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
                    display.sleep();
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Which is just using `display` and not calling `Display.dispose`.

You might also want to look at Eclipse JFace which adds to SWT and provides easier to use dialogs.